# How to handle mqtt loop_forever function when using Django?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, mqtt, paho

I am working on a website and am using Django for development.  I have a few devices that communicate to the website using MQTT, and I plan to use paho-mqtt client.  My issue is that for paho-mqtt to function I must call a function that loops forever while paho-mqtt continues to listen for messages.  What is the best way to have this loop called and contained in it's own thread?

Can I just create a new thread, or should I use something like celery?

Comment: maybe using `celety` is best choice.

Comment: How did you get the integration going in the end? I have a similar case, but I only need to publish stuff, so I'm creating a new mqtt object for each request that needs it. I'm wondering if that wastes resources.

Comment: If you create the client like client.loop_forever() afterwards you call client.loop_start(). Then you just call client.publish("paho/temperature", temperature) when you need.  The loop_forever should handle disconnects and reconnects for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the threaded interface to paho-mqtt instead. This starts a background thread to handle the network processing and can be accessed with `loop_start()`. Alternatively you could make your own thread and just call `loop()` yourself.